# KQL Get DeviceName from DeviceId

Tags: azure, kql

I want to see, what devices my onboarded devices see. For that, I invoke seenby() and need to convert the DeviceId from seenby() to a DeviceName and join it to DeviceId from the seen devices.

```
DeviceInfo
| where OnboardingStatus != "Onboarded"
| summarize arg_max(Timestamp, *) by DeviceId
| join kind=inner (
    DeviceNetworkInfo
    | where IPAddresses contains "10.10."
    //| where IPAddresses contains "10.20."
) on DeviceId 
| where isempty(MergedToDeviceId) 
| invoke SeenBy()
| extend parsed=parse_json(SeenBy)
| extend lastdate=parsed[0]["LastEncountered"]
| extend lastdeviceid=parsed[0]["DeviceId"]
| project DeviceId, DeviceName, DeviceType, SeenBy, lastdate, lastdeviceid
```

kind regards

Comment: it's not clear what `SeenBy()` is - it's likely a user-defined function that is only known to whoever defined it. you should try and clarify what the input to your question is, and what is the desired output, preferably using a clear sample.

Answer (score 0):

We can match the `lastdeviceid` from the previous `join` operation with the `DeviceId` from the `DeviceInfo` records by using `$left.lastdeviceid` and `$right.DeviceId` in the `join` condition.

I modified your query as below:

```bash
DeviceInfo
| where OnboardingStatus != "Onboarded"
| summarize arg_max(Timestamp, *) by DeviceId
| join kind=inner (
    DeviceNetworkInfo
    | where IPAddresses contains "10.10."
    //| where IPAddresses contains "10.20."
) on DeviceId
| where isempty(MergedToDeviceId)
| invoke SeenBy()
| extend parsed = parse_json(SeenBy)
| extend lastdate = parsed[0]["LastEncountered"]
| extend lastdeviceid = parsed[0]["DeviceId"]
| join kind=inner (DeviceInfo) on $left.lastdeviceid == $right.DeviceId
| project DeviceId, DeviceName, DeviceType, SeenBy, lastdate, lastdeviceid
```

[image]

Note: As `seenby()` is a user defined custom function, it showed an empty result according to my table of records in the last 7 days. Try the same one in your environment for the accurate results.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know to use left and right, but it doesnt get me further.

The original query gives a list of Devices (IDs, Names) with the information of seenby(). Seenby also has DeviceId. This has to be converted to DeviceName and linked to the original DeviceId.

Additionally, it has to look like this to work:  ```extend lastdeviceid = tostring(parsed[0]["DeviceId"])```